# How to replace string in BluePrism Calculation

Tags: blueprism

Hi How can I replace the month behind to number in calculation?

Example below Jan will be replace with "1" follow by -[number].

26243-Jan --> **1**-26243

99-Feb --> **2**-99

7328-Mar --> **3**-7328

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? You're much more likely to get help if you can demonstrate how you've tried to solve the problem on your own first.

Comment: I did decision checking as below. But do not know how can I replace it. Therefore asking help here. 

InStr(Trim([intRepOrder]), "Jan")<>0 
OR InStr(Trim([intRepOrder]), "Feb")<>0

Comment: Right, the documentation on string manipulation in Blue Prism is widely available. Have you reviewed it?

Comment: Yes, widely use code stage. thinking if anyone could recommend calculation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
FormatDate("01/" & Right([String], Len([String]) - InStr([String], "-")) & "/2000","MM") & Left([String], Len([String]) - InStr([String], "-"))
```

Data Item String is one of your strings.

Comment: Thanks. This InStr is useful to replace a string. Is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

As the others before me pointed out in the comments, Blue Prism string manipulation guides provide substantial information on how to approach this. There is a function literally called Replace available for the Calculation stage.

However, your examples can also be interpreted as trying to cast string to date. You might want to cut the month name from the end of the string first, and then combine Month() and MakeDate() to retrieve the month serial.